# putting data from a for loop into a table using matlab and fprintf

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, printf

I am trying to put the following data from my for loop into a table formatted so that there are 11 values of F in each column, with a total of 4 columns.

but I am always ending up with one long column of my data instead of the four columns I want. I was wondering if there is some way to put the data into a matrix and then reshape it, but I am having trouble.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
fprintf ('Electrostatic Forces:\n')
 for  r = 1:4;
    q2 = 0: 1*10^-19: 1*10^-18;
        for F = coulomb(q2,r);
            fprintf ('%d\n',F)
    end
end
```

Where the code for the function coulomb is

```
function F = coulomb (q2,r);
k = 8.98*10^9;
q1 = 1.6*10^-19;
F = k*abs(q1*q2)/r^2;
```

end

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is the following:

```
fprintf ('Electrostatic Forces:\n')
q2 = 0: 1*10^-19: 1*10^-18;
for h = 1:numel(q2);

    % Coulomb function
    k = 8.98*10^9;
    q1 = 1.6*10^-19;
    F = k * abs(q1 * q2(h))./[1:4].^2;

    for r = 1:4;
        fprintf('%d ', F(r))
    end
    fprintf('\n')
end
```

Another way is to redefine your function as

```
function F = coulomb (q2, r);
k = 8.98 * 10 ^ 9;
q1 = 1.6 * 10 ^ -19;
F = k * abs(q1 * repmat(q2(:)', numel(r), 1)) ./ (repmat(r(:), 1, numel(q2)) .^ 2);
```

Then you can just type

```
q2 = 0: 1*10^-19: 1*10^-18;
r = 1:4;
F = coulomb(q2, r)'
```

and you will have your table.

Comment: The output I get from that is;0 1.436800e-28 2.873600e-28 4.310400e-28 5.747200e-28 7.184000e-28 8.620800e-28 1.005760e-27 1.149440e-27 1.293120e-27 1.436800e-27 
0 3.592000e-29 7.184000e-29 1.077600e-28 1.436800e-28 1.796000e-28 2.155200e-28 2.514400e-28 2.873600e-28 3.232800e-28 3.592000e-28 
0 1.596444e-29 3.192889e-29 4.789333e-29 6.385778e-29 7.982222e-29 9.578667e-29 1.117511e-28 1.277156e-28 1.436800e-28 1.596444e-28 
0 8.980000e-30 1.796000e-29 2.694000e-29 3.592000e-29 4.490000e-29 5.388000e-29 6.286000e-29 7.184000e-29 8.082000e-29 8.980000e-29 
only the rows should be the columns

Comment: I don't understand: you want that table transposed?

Comment: I have now produced the transposed table.

Comment: If the answer is OK you can consider accepting it (by clicking on the green check mark symbol).